# What does the correspondence theorem tell us about the ideals of $\Bbb Z[x]$ that contain $x^2+1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

> What does the correspondence theorem tell us about the ideals of $\Bbb Z[x]$ that contain $x^2+1$?

If I define $\varphi : \Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z[i]$ as $x \longmapsto i$, then $\ker \varphi = (x^2+1)$.

So by the correspondence theorem an ideal $I$ containing $(x^2+1)$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ corresponds to an ideal $J = \varphi(I) \in \Bbb Z[i]$. However $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a PID so $J = (a+bi)$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb Z$.

Thus $$I = \varphi^{-1}(J) = \varphi^{-1}((a+bi)) = \{g(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid \varphi(g(x)) = g(i)  \in (a+bi) \}.$$

And $g(i) \in (a+bi)$ if and only if $g(i)$ is of the form $(c+di)(a+bi)$ for $c,d,a,b \in \Bbb Z$.

Is there some more information I could get out of here or is this all that the correspondence theorem tells us?

Comment: $\varphi^{-1}(\langle a+bi\rangle)=\langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle$

Comment: @ChrisSanders By definition $\varphi^{-1}((a+bi)) = \{g(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid \varphi(g(x)) = g(i)  \in (a+bi) \}$ and $(x^2 + 1, a +bx) = \{r_1(x^2 + 1) + r_2(a + bx) \mid r_i \in \Bbb Z[x] \}$ so I'm not sure you'll get the equality $$\{g(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid \varphi(g(x)) = g(i)  \in (a+bi) \} = \{r_1(x^2 + 1) + r_2(a + bx) \mid r_i \in \Bbb Z[x] \}$$?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the correspondence theorem, for $K$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $\langle x^2+1\rangle\subseteq K$, we have $\varphi^{-1}(\langle a+bi\rangle)=K\iff \langle a+bi\rangle=\varphi(K)$.

Can you verify that $\langle a+bi\rangle=\varphi(\langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle)$?

$\\$

Something else to think about: when is $\langle a+bi\rangle=\langle c+di\rangle$?

As you know, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID. The only units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are $1,-1,i,-i$.

$\langle a+bi\rangle=\langle c+di\rangle\iff c+di\in\{a+bi,-a-bi,-b+ai,b-ai\}$.

This shows you when it is that $\langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle=\langle x^2+1,c+dx\rangle$.

Comment: I might be confusing something, but are you denoting $K$ as an arbitary ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$ or as the kernel of $\varphi$? The book I have (Artin's algebra) denotes the kernel usually with capital $K$ so that's the source of my confusion... Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: In this answer, $K$ is an ideal, not necessarily the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificiation. As per your other question can I verify that $\langle a+bi\rangle=\varphi(\langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle)$ it is slightly confusing still. This would be true if $K = \langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle$, but $K$ doesn't have any restrictions other than that it's and ideal containing the kernel of $\varphi$. The image $\varphi(K)$ is by definition $$\varphi(K) = \{\varphi(g(x)) \mid g(x) \in K\}$$ and $\langle x^2+1,a+bx\rangle = \{r_1(x^2 + 1) + r_2(a+bx) \mid r_i \in \Bbb Z[x] \}$.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting there as $K = \varphi^{-1}(\langle a + bi \rangle) = \{ p(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid \varphi(p(x)) \in \langle a + bi \rangle \}$ we have that $$\{ p(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid \varphi(p(x)) \in \langle a + bi \rangle \} = \{ p(x) \in \Bbb Z[x] \mid p(i) = z(a+bi), z \in \Bbb Z[i]\}.$$ So I'm looking at those polynomials for which when evaluated at $i$ I'll get $z(a+bi)$ for some $z \in \Bbb Z[i]$. Are these of form $p(x) = (x^2 + 1)q(x) + r(x)$ all? I have that $\varphi(p(x)) = p(i) = r(i)$ and $\deg(r) = 1$ so $p(i) = a+bi$, but I'm missing the coefficient $z$ here still.

Comment: Try $p(x)=(x^2+1)q(x)+(a+bx)s(x)$

Comment: The set of such $p(x)$, where $q,s$ range over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, is an ideal containing $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$

Comment: On the one hand, $p(i)=(a+bi)s(i)\in\langle a+bi\rangle$. On the other hand, if for some integer polynomial $t(x)$ we have $t(i)=z(a+bi)$, then letting $z=c+di$, we have $\varphi(t(x)-(c+dx)(a+bx))=t(i)-z(a+bi)=0$, so $t(x)-(c+dx)(a+bx)\in\text{Ker}(\varphi)=\langle x^2+1\rangle$, so $t(x)=(x^2+1)q(x)+(c+dx)(a+bx)$ for some integer polynomial $q(x)$